# What is the difference between these invocations of COUNT()?

Tags: oracle, aggregate

can anyone please let me know difference between `count(*)`, `count(1)`, `count(0)`, `count('FAST')`

Answer (score 4):

[COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COUNT.html)

[image]

> If you specify expr, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr
>   is not null. You can count either all rows, or only distinct values of
>   expr.
>
> If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function returns all rows,
>   including duplicates and nulls. COUNT never returns null.

`0`, `1`, `'FAST'` are all constant expressions, they are never null, so the query returns all rows.

`*` also returns all rows by definition.

So they all do the same.